# Powershell - Double dashes in parameters

Tags: powershell

Why can't I use double dashes in a parameter?

```
  $yturl = "1JBr27EblVI"

#Works fine
     & $exeYTPath"\youtube-dl.exe" $yturl --write-auto-sub --write-sub --sub-lang sv,en --add-metadata --no-continue --no-overwrites --write-description --write-thumbnail --output "%(uploader)s (%(uploader_id)s)/%(upload_date)s - %(title)s (%(id)s).%(ext)s"

#Does not work     
     $param = "--write-auto-sub --write-sub --sub-lang sv,en --add-metadata --no-continue --no-overwrites --write-description --write-thumbnail"
     & $exeYTPath"\youtube-dl.exe" $yturl $param --output "%(uploader)s (%(uploader_id)s)/%(upload_date)s - %(title)s (%(id)s).%(ext)s"
```

Comment: You are changing how the tokens are parsed. When it is all one string, then that is one token. In your example, you can do `$param = -split "--write-auto-sub --write-sub --sub-lang sv,en --add-metadata --no-continue --no-overwrites --write-description --write-thumbnail"`. Then `$param` will be an array of strings and each element will be a token when stringified.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Problem

If you pass a `$variable` that contains whitespace to a native command, PowerShell will quote the value, so the native executable will receive the whole quoted string as a single argument.

This...

```
 $param = "--write-auto-sub --write-sub --sub-lang sv,en --add-metadata --no-continue --no-overwrites --write-description --write-thumbnail"
 & $exeYTPath"\youtube-dl.exe" $yturl $param --output "%(uploader)s (%(uploader_id)s)/%(upload_date)s - %(title)s (%(id)s).%(ext)s"
```

...will be resolved into something like:

```
 & "C:\Program Files\youtube-dl.exe" https://[...] "--write-auto-sub --write-sub --sub-lang sv,en --add-metadata --no-continue --no-overwrites --write-description --write-thumbnail" --output "%(uploader)s [...]"
```

The 'youtube-dl.exe' will split the commandline into the following five arguments:

- `C:\Program Files\youtube-dl.exe`
- `https://[...]`
- `--write-auto-sub --write-sub --sub-lang sv,en --add-metadata --no-continue --no-overwrites --write-description --write-thumbnail`
- `--output`
- `%(uploader)s [...]`

## Solution

If you want to split a long commandline for readability you can use [array splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-7.1#splatting-with-arrays):

```powershell
$param = @(
    '--write-auto-sub' 
    '--write-sub'
    '--sub-lang', 'sv,en'
    '--add-metadata'
    '--no-continue'
    '--no-overwrites'
    '--write-description'
    '--write-thumbnail'
)
   
& $exeYTPath"\youtube-dl.exe" $yturl @param --output "%(uploader)s (%(uploader_id)s)/%(upload_date)s - %(title)s (%(id)s).%(ext)s"
```

Of course you can also stuff the array into a single line:

```
$param = '--write-auto-sub', '--write-sub', '--sub-lang', 'sv,en', '--add-metadata', '--no-continue', '--no-overwrites', '--write-description', '--write-thumbnail'

& $exeYTPath"\youtube-dl.exe" $yturl @param --output "%(uploader)s (%(uploader_id)s)/%(upload_date)s - %(title)s (%(id)s).%(ext)s"
```